# How to reference a textbox from another form?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to modify existing code to add a popup box. This popup box is another form, and when a user clicks on a button on this form, I want a textbox on the base form to be populated.  After that the popup disappears and then I need to access that value from the textbox on the base form.

The sequence should be:

1. Base form button click calls modal popup
2. Click in button on popup saves value to base form's textbox, then returns control.
3. Base form then uses this value to do something.

Base Form

```vb
Sub base()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "PaperType", , , , , acDialog
    
    MsgBox Me.TheAnswer           'This line gives a null error
End Sub
```

Popup Form

```vb
Private Sub btnRolls_Click()
    'Me.Tag = 1
    Forms!ReceiptDetail_sfrm!TheAnswer = 1
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
    
Private Sub btnSheets_Click()
    'Me.Tag = 4
    Forms!("ReceiptDetail_sfrm").TheAnswer = 4
    Me.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it that way, you probably need something like:

Private Sub btnRolls_Click()
   Forms!ReceiptDetail_sfrm!TheAnswer = 1
   Forms!ReceiptDetail_sfrm.Refresh
   Me.Visible = False
End Sub

I've done what you're doing many times.  I'm not at work to check my code right now for an example, but it's doable.

Comment: The name sfrm suggest that the OP may be trying to post to a subform, which would need: `Forms!MainForm!SubformControlName.Form!TheAnswer`. Alternatively, seeing the pop-up is being hidden, it can be referred to, so TheAnswer could be written to the Tag property of the pop-up and referred to from the main form.

Comment: I reckon you can skip the refresh line.

Answer (score 5):

What I tend to do is hide the popup, then read from it:

**Main Form:**

```
Private Sub base()
   DoCmd.OpenForm "PaperType", , , , , acDialog
   'code waits for modal hide here
   Me!TheAnswer = Forms("PaperType").SomethingOnThatFormThatStoresTheValue
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "PaperType", acSaveNo
   MsgBox Me.TheAnswer
End Sub
```

**Popup**

```
Private Sub btnRolls_Click
   'may be hidden control
   Me.SomethingOnThatFormThatStoresTheValue = TheValueToRead
   Me.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Make sure that either A) Your popup can't be closed from the form itself, or B) Your calling code will handle the error of trying to read something that's no longer loaded (or both).

Comment: The trick of visible = false to cause the calling code to continue when the person clicks on the ok button is a nice trick. up vote + 1.  This apporach means no global vars and has a high reuse ability for the dialog form. And, MORE then one value can be plucked out from the dialog form and again done so without any global vars etc.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently the correct answer is: "Don't do it this way!".  Instead of trying to pass data between the forms, which is a pain, I made a table in Access which only has 1 field in 1 record.  Then I store the value in there using DoCmd.RunSQL, and retrieve it from the other form using DLOOKUP().

Comment: This is by no means the best way to do this.

Comment: Don't worry, I know that.  But at the end of the day, it works and its not slow.  Its ugly code, but trying to use .Tag and trying to reference the form the other ways didn't work for me after hours. I don't have much experience with VBA.

Comment: I don't hand out downvotes lightly.... This may be "not slow" in a single Access file that's on the local machine, but it's a *really* bad habit to get into. Don't involve your data in your code if you can avoid it--and there are several ways to avoid it here. What if you had a slow network between your form and your temp table? Even a global variable smells less bad than this.

Comment: I think the situation does matter, and since this IS a single access file on a local machine, and not some network drive, your network speed concern doesn't apply.  Also, I have to analyze the cost here.  How long can I spend learning more about an old platform before the benefit outweighs the cost?  And concerns about my programming habits don't apply either, as I'm not developing new applications in VBA, and don't intend to.  C#.NET is my platform of choice.

Comment: The alternative solution is not slow, either. And it produces much cleaner code, and keeps the forms re-usable. You're simply wrong here.