# MS Access refresh form and keep position on screen

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have done a lot of searching and found some very elaborate solutions to this problem but it seems like there should just be a simpler way.  I have a form with a navigation subform within it that is based on a query.  In the subform I have a button on each record which brings up a new form to change one of the values. It does an SQL statement to update a table.  I have it so that it refreshes the main form before closing the change form.  This works but it always jumps back up to the first record in the subform.  How do I keep the position of the subform when doing the refresh so it doesn't jump up to the top?  I have seen some solutions that use a bookmark so that it goes back to the record you were on but it might not be in the same position on the screen.  I have also found some elaborate code to keep the scroll position.  I haven't tried this but some people have said that it's a bit "brute force" for what it's doing.

Does someone have a better solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'same position on the screen'? Position in relation to what? If you don't want to return to same record, where do you want to be?

Comment: Don't need UPDATE action to edit record already displayed on form. Just reference form and control to set value. Referencing through a Navigation form is a bit tricky but doable.

Comment: What I meant by 'same position on the screen' is that if a record is in the middle of the screen and you modify it and then refresh, if you use a bookmark it then moves the record to the top of the screen.  I want to change the record without it moving on the screen at all.

Comment: What do you mean in your second comment to reference the form and control to set the value?  How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Then you need to use "brute force" to programmatically scroll the records after refresh/requery. Code behind form displaying record could be as simple as Me!fieldname = "something". Popup form could directly reference other form and its controls to set value of field for record that has focus. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464941/access-vba-trying-to-reference-a-textbox-from-another-form. Referencing a Navigation form is quite similar.

Comment: Actually, first form referencing popup would be simpler, one answer in referenced question demonstrates.